# WPF Cannot Capture Mouse events in Nested CustomControls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have the following Control template in my app.xaml: (it is in a template setter in a style, so there is no key)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type vm:State}">
        <Grid Width="100" Height="60" >
            <Border Margin="4" 
                    IsHitTestVisible="{Binding ElementName=Radio_Edit02, Path=IsChecked}"
                    Padding="4" 
                    BorderBrush="White" 
                    BorderThickness="2" 
                    CornerRadius="5">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      Content="{Binding ItemName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </Border>

            <Grid Margin="3" Background="Transparent">
                <local:Anchor Width="6" Height="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Radio_Edit03, Converter={StaticResource bool2vizibility}}"/>
                <local:Anchor Width="6" Height="6" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Radio_Edit03, Converter={StaticResource bool2vizibility}}"/>
                <local:Anchor Width="6" Height="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Radio_Edit03, Converter={StaticResource bool2vizibility}}"/>
                <local:Anchor Width="6" Height="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Background="Red" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Radio_Edit03, Converter={StaticResource bool2vizibility}}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

State derives from thumb

```
public class State : Thumb, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Anchor derives from UserControl

```
public class Anchor : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

I want to capture a click of the State at one point in the app and of the Anchor in another point of the app.
I want to control when by the two radiobuttons, Radio_Edit02 & Radio_Edit03

when Radio_Edit02 is selected I want to capture the click on the border
when Radio_Edit03 is selected I want to capture the click on the anchor.

I keep getting the click event on the State and cannot get a click on the Anchor.

I tried adding IsHitTestVisible="{Binding ElementName=Radio_Edit03, Path=IsChecked}" to the anchor
but no luck

I tried the following assignement of event handlers in Anchor but neither worked

```
public Anchor() //constructor
    {
        //this//this.MouseLeftButtonUp += onAnchorSelect;
        //this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += onAnchorSelect;
    }
```

signature for onAnchorSelect is

```
public void onAnchorSelect(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

How can I capture a click on the Anchor so that e.Source is the anchor element
thanks

Comment: Did you check in your click event handler, if eventArgs.OriginalSource is the Anchor instance?

Comment: eventArgs.OriginalSource is the State in despite changing the radiobutton

Comment: Where is Radio_Edit02 declared? I do not see it in the scope of the ControlTemplate. Also, did you check, using a dummy converter in the binding for IsHitTestVisible if the value is actually what you expect? Maybe that Binding is has an error?

Comment: Radio_Edit02 & Radio_Edit03 are named controls on the main window

Comment: the IsHitTestVisible binding on border works.
if I move it to a property setter on the state, it blocks all clicks 
so its binding seems to work

Comment: @ChrisOBrien: Try to handle `MouseLeftButtonDown` instead of `MouseLeftButtonUp`. And why would you need the original source in the event handler when you can access the instance using `this`?